# CLR User Defined Type Enum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr

Can I use an Enum as a property type in a CLR User Defined Type?

ex (UDT):

```
public struct MyType
{
    public Enum MyValues
    {
        value1 = 0,
        value2 = 1
    }

    public MyValues Val { get; set; }
}
```

T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @t MyType
SET @t.Val = MyType.MyValues.value2

IF (@t.Val = MyType.MyValues.value1) BEGIN
    PRINT 'value1'
END ELSE BEGIN
    PRINT 'value2'
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive the answer is no, At least not in the way you're thinking.  You would be able to declare the property to be of the Enum type you're interested in, but you would have to employ UserDefined serialization rather than Native.
[User-Defined Type Requirements on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131082.aspx)

Comment: If I were to employ UserDefined serialization, how would that property be able to be used?

Comment: I'd have to double check, but my guess is that from T-SQL it would used as an Int.